# Unable to install apyori package

Tags: python, pip

I got this error when trying to install the package for Apriori algorithm in my virtual env and because the `conda install -c auto apriori` didn't work I tried installing it using pip install and I got this error:

```
  Using cached apyori-1.1.2.tar.gz (8.6 kB)
  ERROR: Error [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python setup.py egg_info
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software
```

However, I came across multiple posts regarding this error and the suggestions that others made were that the anti-virus software is blocking the installation and that I should either reinstall the program or add an exception of the Python local path. I'm using Avast Free and I tried to disable the protection shields temporary but I still get the error.